# Equation of motion for a massless scalar in 2 dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, action, variational-calculus

I'm working through Polchinski's String Theory (Volume 1, Chapter 2, page 34), with $D$ scalar fields:

The action is given by

$$ S = \frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha'}\int d^{2}z \partial X^{\mu} \overline{\partial }X_{\mu}$$

where $\partial := \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$,$\overline{\partial} := \frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}$ and $d^2 z := dz d\overline{z}$

The first order variation of the fields $X_{\mu}$ is:
$$ \delta S = \frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha'} \int d^{2}z \Big[\partial(\delta X^{\mu}) \overline{\partial}X_{\mu} + \partial X^{\mu} \overline{\partial} (\delta X_{\mu}) \Big]$$

We have

$$ \partial(\delta X^{\mu}) \overline{\partial}X_{\mu} = \partial(\delta X^{\mu} \overline{\partial} X_{\mu}) - \delta X^{\mu} \partial \overline{\partial}X_{\mu} $$

and that

$$ \overline{\partial}(\delta X_{\mu} \partial X^{\mu})=\overline{\partial} (\delta X_{\mu} \partial X^{\mu}) - \delta X_{\mu} \overline{\partial} \partial X^{\mu}$$

$\because$ the variations $\delta X_{\mu}$ and $\delta X^{\mu}$ disappear at the boundaries by assumption,

$$ \delta S = -\frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha'} \int d^2 z(\delta X^{\mu} \partial \overline{\partial} X_{\mu} + \delta X_{\mu} \overline{\partial} {\partial} X^{\mu}) $$

How do I raise and lower indices to get to the equation of motion

$$ \partial \overline{\partial} X^{\mu} = 0?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. Polchinski himself states that the metric on the fields is the flat Minkowski metric $\eta^{\mu \nu}$. Using this leads easily to the equation of motion.